# Using the word marooned in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Mumbai city is marooned in rains.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
I have read some sentence formations in Collins dictionary but couldn't understand how to use it in a sentence. There were many forms:

1) He spent twenty-four hours marooned in the cab of his vehicle. (marooned is here followed by preposition in)

2) I was temporarily marooned at home by my injured knee.(marooned is here followed by preposition at)

Comment: When not using it to mean actually being stranded alone on a desolate island, the figurative use should have some sense of that meaning.  Your sentence doesn’t seem to have that.

Comment: Isn't it "Mumbai city is colored in maroon by rain", or "People were marooned in Mumbai city by rain"? Or is "Mumbai city" figuratively associated with the color "maroon"?

Comment: I actually intended to say that life of people in Mumbai city got stranded due to rains.

Comment: The OED, under adj *marooned* provides this example. 1995   *Times 9 June 17/2   The marooned remnants of the West Pier await a deep-pocketed saviour.* If a pier can become marooned, why not a whole city?

Comment: @Jim The original sense of *maroon* certainly did not imply being alone. It  involved a whole community of slaves - hence the word *maroon* i.e. brownish red. *Marooned* has now long been used in all senses of something or someone being unable to escape because of surrounding water.

Comment: "Marooned", in it's figurative sense, means "isolated".  Can you replace "marooned" with "isolated" in your sentences and still obtain the intended meaning?

Comment: @WS2 - I think a city could be marooned in flood water *because* of the rain.  But I have a hard time seeing being marooned ***in*** rains.

Comment: @WS2 - I think it can be used even more broadly than "because of surrounding water." _They left their friend marooned at the night club_ doesn't mean the friend was standing on a table in a flooded club, it just means the friend had to find another ride home.

Comment: @WS2 I didn't know about its genesis. I was simply trying to form a sentence with this word.Thanks.

Comment: @TanushreeDutta  *The early maroons are celebrated for their resistance to European plantation owners, and for their fortitude and capacity to survive in remote and inhospitable regions. The independence of the Jamaican maroons was recognized by two treaties agreed with the British in 1738/9, which brought to an end the First Maroon War. One of the leaders of the Jamaican maroons in the 18th cent. (‘Nanny of the Maroons’) is now honoured as a National Hero of Jamaica.* (OED) The actual word *maroon* is from French *marron* meaning "chestnut".

Comment: Your parenthetical statements have me wondering if you're under the (erroneous) assumption that all verbs get paired with a certain preposition every time they are used.

Answer (score 1):

To pull together the comments and answer your question, your original sentence "Mumbai city is marooned in rains." doesn't sound right as "in rains" doesn't evoke being surrounded by water. You then need to decide whether it is the whole of Mumbai (a single entity), or it's people (which could be many separate groups), who have been marooned as these two sentences have subtly different meanings:

- "Mumbai City has been marooned by the flooding"
- "The people of Mumbai have been marooned by the floods."

Comment: The second bullet point is correct. "Marooned" is normally taken with one, several or many people as its subject - e.g. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/marooned. One could talk sensibly about marooning an animal or, at a stretch, inanimate objects which otherwise could move (e.g. a car) but the idea of using the city? Probably not - use a word like "isolated" instead.

Comment: In order for something to be marooned, one might consider that it desires to be elsewhere.  Otherwise the marooned object might be content to be where it is, meaning that is not marooned.  You might, in certain situations refer to inanimate objects as being marooned but I would suggest that such constructions carry a level of humorous irony created by the fact that the object is inanimate and cannot be marooned.  Consider the sentence, "His fishing pole remained marooned in the garage."  This is not a comment so much about the fishing pole as it is about the state of the person's fishing.

Comment: Thanks for your additional insights. (Fishing pole example)

Comment: @JonLarby Shouldn't it be "Mumbai city is marooned in floods"? Doesn't the sentence "Mumbai City has been marooned by the flooding" means that the city was left stranded by the floods, whereas I meant to say that city is stranded in floods.